# How to concatenate characters?

Tags: c++

I am trying to concatenate character from string to check if it is a word.
Example:

```
string s1 = "battle";
string s2 = "all";
string s3 = "lolo";
string s4 = "leaf";

string s5 = s1[0] + s2[0] + s3[0] + s4[0]
```

but s5 is sum of unicodes, not concatenation. I also tried by using append method like

```
string s5 = "";
s5.append(s1[0]);
```

But this says that no matching function to call.
I will be grateful for any help

Comment: `string s5 = string() + s1[0] + s2[0] + s3[0] + s4[0];` would be one way.

Comment: `s5.push_back(s1[0]);` would be another.

Comment: I wonder if `string s5 = {s1[0], s2[0], s3[0], s4[0], '\0'};`  works? [update: It does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b72ed2ff2084fa0)

Comment: @MooingDuck the `'\0'` is not needed. `std::string`'s will take care of that itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck It wouldn't use `basic_string(std::initializer_list<CharT>, const Allocator& = Allocator())`?

Comment: @aschepler: Oh, I forgot that one, and the link I glanced at didn't have that.  That's probably it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yup, including the null gives a string with size 5: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46fd50e0e9272db

Comment: If you can't initialize with `{....}`, you can also use `s5 += s1[0]; s5 += s2[0]; ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to achieve what you want:

```
std::string s1 = "battle";
std::string s2 = "all";
std::string s3 = "lolo";
std::string s4 = "leaf";

{
    // thanks to Mooing Duck for this one
    std::string s5 = {s1[0], s2[0], s3[0], s4[0]/*, '\0'*/};
    std::cout << s5 <<  "\n";
}
{
    // thanks to  Igor Tandetnik for this one
    std::string s5 = std::string() + s1[0] + s2[0] + s3[0] + s4[0];
    std::cout << s5 <<  "\n";
}
{
    std::string s5;
    for (const auto &str : { s1, s2, s3, s4 })
        s5.push_back(str.at(0));
    std::cout << s5 <<  "\n";

}
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << s1[0] << s2[0] << s3[0] << s4[0];
    std::string s5 = ss.str();
    std::cout << s5 << "\n";
}
{
    std::string s5 = std::string(1, s1[0]) + std::string(1, s2[0]) + std::string(1, s3[0]) + std::string(1, s4[0]);
    std::cout << s5 << "\n";
}
{
    std::string s5;
    s5.resize(4);
    s5[0] = s1[0];
    s5[1] = s2[0];
    s5[2] = s3[0];
    s5[3] = s4[0];
    std::cout << s5 << "\n";
}
{
    std::string s5;
    s5 += s1[0];
    s5 += s2[0];
    s5 += s3[0];
    s5 += s4[0];
    std::cout << s5 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Also your first sample can be simplified: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103474/how-to-concatenate-characters?noredirect=1#comment100727909_57103474

Comment: There is also `s5.append(&s1[0], 1); ...` and `s5.append(s1.begin(), s1.begin()+1); ...`